# integrability of random variables

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I face a question when reading a book on Levy Process. When proving that a Levy process with bounded jumps has finite moments, the book shows something like 
$P\{|X|>2nC\}\leq \alpha^n$, where $C$ is a constant, then claims that this implies $X$ is integrable. Maybe it is very simple, but I don't quite understand how $X$ is integrable?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that $\alpha < 1$:

$$\int_{\Omega}{|X| dP}=\int_{\mathbb{R^+}}{xdP^{|X|}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{2nC}^{2(n+1)C}xdP^{|X|}$$
$$\leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(2nC<|X|) \cdot 2(n+1)C\leq\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\alpha^n2(n+1)C<\infty$$

Answer (score 2):

You may remember from elementary probability theory that, for a positive integrable random variable $X$ with density $f$,
$$
\mathbb{E}X = \int_{\mathbb{R}^+}{xf(x)\mathbb{d}x} = \int_{\mathbb{R}^+}[1-F(x)]\mathbb{d}x,
$$
where $F$ is the cumulative distribution function of $X$.

You should be able to use this relation to show that a positive random variable $X$ is integrable (wrt to $\mathbb{d}\mathbb{P}$) if and only if $1-F(x)=\mathbb{P}(X>x)$ is integrable (wrt to $\mathbb{d}x$).

The additional complications arising from the fact that in your case $X$ is not positive, and $1-F(x)$ is bounded explicitly only for $x$ of the form $2nC$ are minor.